# how to implement a button to switch in another view

Tags: ios

i'm new to developing with xcode,and i'm following the apple's tutorial:"Second's ios app tutorial". I've add a button to my scene "Add Sighting View Controller",and i want to switch this view to another(BirdsViewController)that have a list of bird's names. in my storyboard i've create a segue between the button and BirdsViewController and also connect the button to touch up inside, but when i run the app the button doesn't appear.Can anybody help me?thank you.
here's my code(i don't have implemented any other methods):

AddSightingViewController.h

```
@class BirdSighting;

@interface AddSightingViewController : UITableViewController  

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *birdNameInput;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *locationInput;

@property (strong, nonatomic) BirdSighting *birdSighting;

@property (strong, nonatomic)  UIButton *showBirds;

-(IBAction)displayBirds:(id)sender;
```

AddSightingViewController.m

```
#import "AddSightingViewController.h"

#import "BirdSighting.h"

#import "BirdsViewController.h"

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@class BirdSighting;

@interface AddSightingViewController ()

@end

@implementation AddSightingViewController

@synthesize showBirds;

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    if((textField == self.birdNameInput) || (textField == self.locationInput)) {

        [textField resignFirstResponder];   
    }
      return YES;    
}
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ReurnInput"]) {

        if ([self.birdNameInput.text length] || [self.locationInput.text length])

        {
            BirdSighting *sighting;

            NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

            sighting = [[BirdSighting alloc] initWithName:self.birdNameInput.text
                                             location:self.locationInput.text date:today];

            self.birdSighting = sighting;
        }    
    }   
}

 BirdsViewController *viewController;

-(IBAction)showBirds:(id)sender {

    viewController =
    [[BirdsViewController alloc]
     initWithNibName:@"BirdsViewController" bundle:nil];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any allocation and adding of button as subview to the viewcontroller's view.

I think in the app like other textfields, button is also IBOutlet. Declare button as an IBOutlet and connect the outlet to the button in the interface builder file.

@property (weak, nonatomic)  IBOutlet UIButton *showBirds;

Or allocate the button and add as subview to viewcontroller's view.

Comment: I declared the button in interface : @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *showBirds(connected to IB)                       and added the method in implementation:                                    BirdsViewController *viewController;

-(void)showBirds:(id)sender {
    [UIButton alloc];
    [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
}   the button isn't displayed in the ios simulator.